# Display flexbox both side by side and up and down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this structure:

```
<div class="quizForm">
    <div class="quizQuestions"></div>
    <div class="quizQuestions"></div>
    <div class="quizQuestions"></div>
    <div class="quizImage"></div>
</div>
```

the "quizQuestions" after the first are hidden, and appear when the user go to the next question.

What I want to achieve is this:
[image]

Where the quizQuestions are in columns and the quizImage is on the right side.

I have:

```
.quizForm{
  display: flex;
}

.quizQuestions{
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.quizImage{
  flex: 2;
}
```

But in that way the quizQuestions too go side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `quizQuestions` in a container and then use `flexbox` with `flex-direction: column`

```css
.quizForm {
  display: flex;
}

.quiz-questions-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.quizImage {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="quizForm">
  <div class="quiz-questions-container">
    <div class="quizQuestions"> quizQuestions </div>
    <div class="quizQuestions"> quizQuestions </div>
    <div class="quizQuestions"> quizQuestions </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quizImage"> quizImage </div>
</div>
```